# Firebase v9 Firestore create document by id in React JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can i access to the document id?

I tried using doc().id but it doesnt work, how i can do it?

```
await addDoc(collection(db, 'users', currentUser.uid, 'proyects', doc().id, 'tasks'), {
            name: tarea,
            userUid: currentUser.uid,

        })
```

[image: This is a capture of firestore, and i want to get the doc id of every document inside the proyects collection. And then create a collection named tasks inside of every of those documents.]

This is a capture of firestore, and i want to get the doc id of every document inside the proyects collection. And then create a collection named tasks inside of every of those documents.

Comment: What determines which document it goes into? Or are you applying the new data to all of the documents in the `proyects` collection? Collections are also only created if they hold data.

Comment: @samthecodingman Oh true, I want to add the "tasks" collection with the data to all projects. In other words, all those documents within the "projects" collection, will have the "tasks" collection inside with the same data. Also, how could you create a collection to a specific document in the collection of projects?

Answer (score 2):

If the intention is to automatically create a new document ID using `doc().id` you would use:

```
const userProjectsColRef = collection(db, 'users', currentUser.uid, 'projects');
const newProjectDocRef = doc(userProjectsColRef);
addDoc(collection(newProjectDocRef, 'tasks'), {
  /* ... data ... */
});
```

This is because then first argument must be present and it must be either an instance of `Firestore`, `CollectionReference`, or `DocumentReference`. In order to use the automatically generated ID, you must pass in a `CollectionReference`.

Comment: My idea is to get the id of the document and add a collection inside the document called "tasks". I Edit my question with a photo with more details of what I am looking for :)